# Suggestion for fastest PHP web page caching for many thousands of pages?

Tags: php, caching, mongodb, redis, flat-file

I'm looking for the best solution for caching thousands of web pages. Right now I am using flat files, which works great until there's many thousands of flat files, then the entire file system slows down (a lot) when accessing the cache of files (Running on CentOS with EXT3 under OpenVZ). I'd like to explore other options such as Redis or MongoDB as a substitute, but would they be any faster? And if not, what would be the best suggestion?

My system dynamically creates over 40K pages per website, so it's not feasible to do a memory cache either.

Thanks!!

Comment: "Best" is an awfully relative term.

Comment: SSD would be great but out of the price range. Wouldn't mind using the hard drive, but it seems the native file system slows down so much once there's a lot of files, which is the reason why I'm curious if Mongo/Redis is a better solution with such a large cache?

Comment: Good point Jared. Changed it to "fastest". I'd hope that people would know what I meant tho ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file cache is fine, you just have to be smart about it. I'd aim to keep directorys to, say, 500 entries or less. with 40k entries, just hashing the url and using the first 2 bytes of the  hash will give you 255 folders, each of which should contain on average ~150 files.

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thank you and Jonas for having this similar answer (must be the best) :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I know StackExchange uses Redis on CentOS, so it should be even better from a LAMP stack. Redis seems to be optimized for that sort of thing, whereas MongoDB is more of an actual database. You could also use memcached.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest spreading the files in subdirectories, possibly grouped by the first two or three characters of the md5 hash of the name of the cache file (or just the first two or five characters of the file name). This takes a bit of load off the file system.

Comment: I thought of this, but wasn't sure if it would make an improvement. This makes sense for sure and would be easy to implement for me. Would  this still be faster than Redis as the other guy suggests?

Comment: I have no idea. This is just an independent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using something like Varnish?  Depending on what you're caching and how complicated your invalidation is, it could work for you.  You would create your pages dynamically and let proxy layer handle any duplicate requests.

https://www.varnish-cache.org/